# Finding spring bean references?

Tags: eclipse, spring

IDEs like eclipse have that fance feature to follow a method-call by Ctrl-click or to find callers using Ctrl+Shift+G.

In *.spring.xml one can Ctrl-click on a referenced class. That is fine.

Is there anyway to find out something about references between beans?

E.g.:

Where is this bean referenced in other .spring.xmls?

Where is this bean reference defined?

Answer (score 2):

The closest to it is **Spring Explorer View found in Spring Tool Suite**. There you can explore your bean configurations and even see the Dependency graph (graphical representation of your bean configuration)

STS is SpringSource's build of Eclipse which includes Spring tools and a lot more. It can be downloaded for free from http://www.springsource.com/downloads/sts

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA also has [Spring bean dependency graph viewer](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/spring-dependencies-diagram.html).